# Given some event is bound to happen in the future, how to compute its probability at a given time?

Tags: probability

Starting from time $ t_0 $ to $ t_0 + T $ ($ T \ge 0$), some event $ E $ is bound to happen $ P(E) = 1 $, and it will only happen once. It is unknown when it will happen, but the probability that $ E $ will happen increases as the time passes. How to compute the probability of $ E $ at a given time $ t_0 + t $.

$$
P(E|t_0+t) = ?
$$

### Update

According to the comments, I think I need to find a $ f(t) $ which, $ f(t_0) = 0 $ and $ f(t_0 + T) = 1 $, then I need to work out the integral.

$$
F(X) = \int_{t_0}^{t_0 + T}{f(x)}
$$

So I have.

$$
f(x) =
\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    0 & x = t_0 \\
    1 & x = t_0 + T \\
    ? & t_0 \lt x \lt t_0 + T
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

But I no idea what $ f(x) $ be like in the last scenario. What if I *assume* it is $ \frac{1}{T - x} $? How to compute the integral of this function?

Comment: Seems like any concave upwards function $f$ with $f(t_0)=0$ and $f(t_0+T)=1$ could be the CDF for the distribution.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I am not math pro. Please let me know if you think I missed anything.

Comment: There are (infinitely) many functions that satisfy your requirement.  Any one that is $0$ at $t_0$, $1$ at $t_0+T$ and monotonically increasing will do.  For starters, it could be certain to happen at some time in the interval, so the function is a step.  It could be uniform, so be a straight line between the endpoints.  There are many more.  You need more information.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda get the idea. But I am not solving a math quiz, I am trying to work out a formula to estimate real life event. I kinda feel the longer I wait, the more likely it will happen. That's why I assume $ \frac{1}{T-x} $. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be the time that the event occurs, and assume that $\mathcal{L}(X) = F_{\mathbf{X}}$, for some distribution function $F_{\mathbf{X}} \colon \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathopen[0, 1\mathclose]$. Notation: For each real $t > 0$, let $F_{\mathbf{X}}(t)^{-}$ denote the left-side limit $$F_{\mathbf{X}}(t)^{-} := \lim_{\substack{s \in \mathbb{R}_{+} \\ s \nearrow t}} F_{\mathbf{X}}(s).$$ We convene that $F_{\mathbf{X}}(0)^{-} := F_{\mathbf{X}}(0)$. Given your question, it is naturally to assume that $$ \mathrm{supp}(F_{\mathbf{X}}) \subset \mathopen[t_{0}, \infty \mathclose). $$ Due to the elementary properties of the distribution function, we have (assuming the event is bound to happen in $\mathopen[t_{0}, t_{0}+T \mathclose]$): $$F_{\mathbf{X}}(t_{0}^{-}) = 0, \quad F_{\mathbf{X}}(t_{0}+T) = 1, $$ as well as $$ F_{\mathbf{X}}(t) = \mathbb{P}\mathopen[ \mathbf{X} \le t \mathclose], \quad t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}. $$ Note that distribution functions are right-continuous as well as non-decreasing by definition, and $$\mathbb{P}\mathopen[\mathbf{X} = t \mathclose] = F_{\mathbf{X}}(t) - F_{\mathbf{X}}(t)^{-}, \quad t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}. $$ This implies that $\mathbb{P}\mathopen[ \mathbf{X} = t \mathclose] = 0$, whenever $F_{\mathbf{X}}$ is continuous at $t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, which provides a partial solution to your question: if you choose a continuous distribution function, then the probability that the event occurs at any given time $t$ equals $0$. This means that, if you want to allow certain times $t \in \mathopen[t_{0}, t_{0}+T \mathclose]$ to have a positive event probability $p_{t} > 0$, then $F_{\mathbf{X}}$ needs to jump (i.e., be discontinuous) there.

Considering continuous distributions, you can take the approach of constructing / choosing a density function $f \colon \mathbb{R}_{+} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that $$F_{\mathbf{X}}(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x, \quad t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}.$$ Naturally, there are lots of popular solutions to this problem, an elementary one being the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) on the interval $\mathopen[t_{0}, t_{0}+T \mathclose]$, or the [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

Considering distributions that allow for event-times with positive probability, you could define for a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ real constants $a_{0}, a_{1},..., a_{n}$ and event times $t_{0} < t_{1} < t_{2} < ... < t_{n} < t_{n+1} = t_{0}+T$ and set $$ F_{\mathbf{X}}(t) := \sum_{k = 0}^{n} a_{k} 1_{\mathopen[t_{k}, t_{k+1} \mathclose)}(t) + 1_{\mathopen[t_{n+1}, \infty \mathclose)}, $$ which amounts to assigning positive event probabilities to the times $t_{0} < t_{1} < t_{2} < ... < t_{n} < t_{n+1} = t_{0}+T$, namely $$ \mathbb{P}\mathopen[X = t_{i} \mathclose] = a_{i} - a_{i-1}, \quad i \in \{1, ..., n\},$$ as well as $\mathbb{P}\mathopen[X = t_{0} \mathclose] = a_{0}$ and $\mathbb{P}\mathopen[X = t_{n+1} \mathclose] = 1-a_{n}$. Obviously, there are many more possibilities, like sending $n \to \infty$, and making use of some convergent series theory. And finally, both the time-continuous and -discrete approach can be combined, depending on how you want to model the distribution of $\mathbf{X}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the event can happen literally at *any time* in the time interval
$[t_0, t_0+T],$ where we assume "any time" means the time could be any real number in that interval, then the usual assumption would be that the probability distribution is continuous over that interval and that the probability it will occur exactly at a given time $t$ (where $t$ is some given number, $t_0 < t < t_0 + T$), is **zero** for every possible value of $t.$

But if $F(t)$ is the probability that $E$ occurs at or before time $t,$
$t_0 < t < t_0 + T,$
then you can say that

$$
F(t) =
  \begin{cases}
    0 & t \leq t_0 \\
    1 & t \geq t_0 + T \\
    p \text{ for some $p \in[0,1]$} & t_0 < t < t_0 + T
  \end{cases}
$$

And if the distribution of $E$ over the time interval $[t_0, t_0+T]$ is a continuous distribution, you can set $f(t) = F'(T)$ so that

$$
F(t) = \int_{t_0}^{t_0 + t} f(x)\,\mathrm dx.
$$

Note $t_0+t$ rather than $t_0+T$ at the upper end of the integral.
If you really want to integrate from $t_0$ to $t_0+T,$ the conditions you have given imply that
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_0 + T} f(x)\,\mathrm dx = 1.
$$

Based on the few facts you have given, in fact, $f$ could be *any function*
for which $\int_{t_0}^{t_0 + T} f(x)\,\mathrm dx = 1.$
In fact you could take any integrable function $g$ and set

$$
f(t) =
  \begin{cases}
    0 & t < t_0 \\[1ex]
    \dfrac{g(t)}{\int_{t_0}^{t_0 + T} g(x)\,\mathrm dx}
     & t_0 \leq t \leq t_0 + T \\[1ex]
    0 & t > t_0 + T.
  \end{cases}
$$

This leaves a lot of options for what distribution to choose. Really a lot of options. Probably a lot more than you want.
You might want to see if there is something else you can say about the probability of when $E$ will occur.